# Always on top for MS Word using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, always-on-top

Hi this is my first post in here, sorry for wrong posting. I need always on top MS Word so I can take note while webex meeting. I cannot install any software like AHK, as this is company policy

I found a way to always on top for excel using VBA from extendoffice.com [Link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2030-keep-excel-window-on-top.html)

Following are the programming

```
'Update 20140909
\#If Win64 Then
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos \_
Lib "user32" ( \_
ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, \_
ByVal hwndInsertAfter As LongPtr, \_
ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, \_
ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, \_
ByVal wFlags As Long) \_
As Long
\#Else
Public Declare Function SetWindowPos \_
Lib "user32" ( \_
ByVal hwnd As Long, \_
ByVal hwndInsertAfter As Long, \_
ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, \_
ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, \_
ByVal wFlags As Long) \_
As Long
\#End If
Public Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Public Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Public Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
Public Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2
Sub ShowXLOnTop(ByVal OnTop As Boolean)
Dim xStype As Long
\#If Win64 Then
Dim xHwnd As LongPtr
\#Else
Dim xHwnd As Long
\#End If
If OnTop Then
xStype = HWND_TOPMOST
Else
xStype = HWND_NOTOPMOST
End If
Call SetWindowPos(Application.hwnd, xStype, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOMOVE)
End Sub
Sub SetXLOnTop()
ShowXLOnTop True
End Sub
Sub SetXLNormal()
ShowXLOnTop False
End Sub
```

I tried on excel and its really work. but when tried on Word using VBA for Word, error with following description:

Compile Error:
Method or data member not found(picture)
[Error location screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l6ln.png)

I tried to change
`Call SetWindowPos(Application.hwnd, xStype, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOMOVE)`
to
`Call SetWindowPos(Window.Hwnd, xStype, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOMOVE)`
[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.window.hwnd)

still not working. can anyone help me. my skills in programming is basic, as I only copy and paste people program only. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change

`Call SetWindowPos(Application.hwnd, xStype, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOMOVE)`

to

```
Call SetWindowPos(ActiveWindow.hwnd, xStype, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE Or SWP_NOMOVE)
```

`Application.hwnd` is for excel https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.hwnd

`ActiveWindow.hwnd` is for word https://www.codevba.com/Word/Window/Hwnd.htm#.Y8ShmI4zYuU